# Why is this exception null?

Tags: java, android, exception, try-catch

Obviously this is a simplified example, but it makes my point. I'm working with a 3rd party SDK and ran into this scenario and I'm able to reproduce it with the below code.

```
try {
    java.util.List<java.lang.String> nullList;
    nullList = null;

    for(java.lang.String s : nullList){}
}
catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code will throw an exception which is caught, but `e` is always null. Why is that?

**update**
I copied the code to a new method and `e` is no longer null. I'm going to follow up with JetBrains as I'm using IntelliJ. Perhaps it's an issue on their end.

Comment: Did you mean `e` is a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: The nullpointer exception should/will get throw on the foreach loop.

Comment: We need more details.

Comment: put it into your IDE. The Exception object, e is null. Not many more details than that to provide.

Comment: I'm telling you guys, I'm not a complete idiot here. e = null. NOT e.message. not e = NullReference etc. e = null. Try it before you comment/answer. This doesn't seem correct to me, but I'm not a huge java guy so I didn't know if this scenario is possible.

Comment: What 3rd party SDK? This is impossible without some serious byte code manipulation.

Comment: Post the stack trace and line numbers. If `e` is `null`, `e.printStackTrace()` will throw its own `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I'm not using the 3rd party sdk to reproduce this. i'm using the code above directly.

Comment: Why do you write `java.lang.String` instead of just `String`? You can also assign `nullList` at the same time you declare it, and replace the braces after the `for` with a semicolon.

Comment: trying. As I noted above, once I started moving the code around it's no longer turning up null. I think the IDE is jacked. Intellisense is not working either which makes me suspect the ide.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the exception caught in the catch block, it cannot possibly be null, but its *message* can be null.

Comment: I thought the same thing which is why I'm asking. I wouldn't ask if `e` wasn't null.

Comment: It can't be null in the catch block. How are you establishing that it's null? and where?

Comment: in debug mode, I hover over the `e` and `e=null`. I open up the expression evaluator and type `e` and get `result=null`. In the debugger variables windows `e=null`. `System.out.println(e==null)` prints `true`. I'm investigating IDE issues right now. I moved the code around and now I'm getting the expected NPE.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not null, while running the code it does give me the following stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Trialstuff.main(Trialstuff.java:7)
```

Comment: Trialstuff is the class name so ignore that

Comment: true, it's actually a `NullPointerException` being thrown. But even so, why is `e` null? Even if I catch the more specific `NullPointerException`, this is still the case.

Comment: Its because the NullPointerException is not getting thrown. You are catching it in your catch statement. If you remove the e.printStackTrace(); from catch block, the code will run without outputting anything about the error.

Answer (score 1):

e is not null, replace **e.printStackTrace()** by:

```
System.out.println(e==null);
```

That will tell you that is not null, that will print **false**

e is **java.lang.NullPointerException**, dont get confused with null

Comment: this shows `System.out﹕ true`

Comment: No, thats not possible. Copy the code, paste it in a main method and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop where the exception seems to be occurring is equivalent to

```
List list = nullList;
for (Iterator iterator = nullList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    s = (String)iterator.next();
}
```

so should be throwing an `NPE` rather than a `null` value when tryng to access the `iterator` method for the `nullList` variable

This [Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/AdBWns) shows that `e` is a `NullPointerException`

Comment: nope. e=null. I'm not a big java guy so I didn't know if it was a possible scenario. Seemed odd to me.